# Forcing a subclass to define a protected final instance variable

Tags: java, static, subclass, final, protected

Sometimes I need a property in the superclass (e.g. `ChessFigure`) that should force the subclass (e.g. `Pawn` or `Bishop`) to implement a const (`final`) property. For example every Chess figure has its own Image, but it's `static` (but only static for the subclass, so I can't use it in the superclass as static) and `final`.

How could I implement this in the superclass ChessFigure in a professional way?

Comment: Did you consider an `abstract` getter instead of a field (property) ? Concrete child classes are then forced to implement it.

Comment: @vikingsteve Yes that's my current "solution".

Answer (score 1):

You cannot force a subclass to declare a variable, independently of the access modifier of it (e.g., public, protected, private).

As @vikingsteve mentioned, probably the best option is to use an abstract method that each subclass overrides according to its needs, maybe referencing constant values defined by the subclass.

Besides, you may also like to change your implementation in the future, say using a properties file for defining the images of your chess figures instead of hardcoded constants in the code. Using a method that encapsulates the logic for finding the right image (either returning a constant, reading a property file, or whatever) is going to facilitate the evolution and maintenance of your code.

Comment: Yes that's my current solution. But the ugly thing is that I have to write final properties for the ImagePath (or the Spritesheet position) in every subclass. It's not like DRY because the getter is the same, and the final properties are the same.

Comment: but that is probably the best solution. If you are using constants to refer to those images, you may also name those constant variables by the real image they represent (e.g., like 'PAWN_IMAGE', 'BISHOP_IMAGE' and so on) instead of using a generic name for all.

Answer (score 1):

You are complicating your design. A better solution is

```
enum ChessFigure {
  KING, QUEEN, ROOKS, KNIGHTS, BISHOPS, PAWNS;
  Image blackImage, whiteImage; // to be filled
}
```

the image variables might be declared `final` if you initialize them within the enum’s constructor.

or, if you want to separate logic from presentation:

```
enum ChessFigure {
  KING, QUEEN, ROOKS, KNIGHTS, BISHOPS, PAWNS
}
```

…

```
// within presentational code:
EnumMap<ChessFigure,Image> blackFigureImages;
EnumMap<ChessFigure,Image> whiteFigureImages;
```

---

If you are thinking about mutable figures, e.g. to hold the board location, use can use a different class, e.g.

```
class BoardFigure {
  final ChessFigure type;
  int row, column;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a read-only property. `final` is not the only way to achieve this. In my example very class can get the path to the image but only the subclasses and the classes in the package can change the path.

```
public abstract class ChessFigure {
   private static String imagePath;

   protected static void setPath(String imagePath) {
      this.imagePath = imagePath;
   }

   public static String getPath() {
      return imagePath;
   }
}
```

Comment: But in this way every subclass has the same imagePath after setting it. F.g. if I call getImagePath of every element in my chessFigureArray it would return the same imagePath.